# Unexpected content from default.ctp on test.php page after fatal error

Tags: testing, cakephp-2.1

When I run a test that throws a PHP fatal error, I see my default layout (View/Layouts/default.ctp) in the output, inside CakePHP's core layout for test.php.  This only happens when a fatal error occurs.  Worse, content about the error is injected into the middle of some of my styled artifacts inside default.ctp, making it hard to read.

If I run a test, especially a test that does not invoke a controller, why should render() ever be called on my default layout for content?

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged 'cakephp-2.1' but could you be using a Cake core of version 2.2? This version has introduced the new `error layout`.
You should copy this file from: `lib/Cake/View/Layouts/error.ctp` to: `app/View/Layouts/`.

Check the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html).